# What is this cable/hose management clip? (picture)

Tags: accessories, cable

I've purchased a RockShox Reverb seat post, and its come with these delightful little Cable/Hose clips.  Since my bike frame only comes with built in cable clips for the brakes and shifters, these little guys allow you to attach your cables to existing cables.  Problem is, I don't know what they are called or where to buy more because I'd like some more :D

**Anyone know what these are called and where I can buy more?**

[image: Cable/Hose management clip]

Comment: Use a cable tie, bro.

Comment: You mean a zip tie?  I'm a little bit of a neat freak, this are much cleaner looking and effective because I don't need pieces of the frame near by in order to wrap around.  Also, zip ties put pressure on the cable housing.  Its OK for break cables and shifter cables, but I'd rather not for my hydraulic hose.

Comment: Seriously buddy?! Like how tight are you pulling those zip ties? In that case use coloured electrical tape.

Comment: I can't find them anywhere either. Did you get them on a new post or do you think someone might have repurposed them from another application?

Comment: Small velcro ties also work, they come in different sizes, in matching colors, and they're reusable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bike parts.com lists them as Sram rotating dual line hooks # BPC 147851.

Comment: http://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=41885&category=1613

Comment: Awesome!!! I like these things.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find these cable clips or don't want to pay a high price for those you can find, I'd suggest that some clear vinyl tubing of the proper inside diameter and cut to the desired length, then split open and placed around two cables wherever you desired, may work fine. The vinyl tubing is soft, so it won't scratch paint or cut any cables. You can find the tubing in most hardware stores and it's sold by the foot. It would cost pennies as compared to any clips.

Comment: Good idea - I've seen the same thing done but cut spirally, so the original piece of tube is ~5 cm long and you spiral cut around it, to make a curly piece about 10 cm long, which holds itself around the targets.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon sell these and few on-line bike shops have them. I guess they wasn't available when you posted the original question. You can find them from either Sram or Jagwire brands and they look to be the same.